# OnDestroy not triggers when we clear the Activities stack using FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK

Tags: android, android-activity, back-stack

In android, Let's assume I have the below activities

> Activity A -> Activity B -> Activity C -> Activity D

In some scenarios, I have to directly navigate from Activity D to Activity A (Example: Logout scenario).  In such case, I am using the below method to clear the `backstack` and navigate to Activity A.  It is nothing but like killing & opening the app again.

```
        // Go to LoginActivity.java
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class);
        intent.addFlag(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
```

It is absolutely working fine! No doubts on it.

**What I need now?**

When I navigate from Activity D to A (using **`FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK`**.)  I would expect `OnDestroy()` method of Activity D, C, B to execute. But it is not currently hitting/triggering.

**Why I am expecting `OnDestroy` method to call?**

I would need to invoke one trackevent(de-register) method from all the activities when clearing the back stack. Eg: From Activity D, C and B. Hence, I expect the `OnDestroy` method to invoke (or any method is also fine).  Please assist me on this?

Comment: You shouldn't count on onDestroy method. There are situations where the system simply kills an activity without firing the onDestroy callback. 

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onDestroy()

Answer (score 2):

According to docs

> **FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP**: If an instance of the Activity to be launched already exists in the back stack, **destroy any other Activity on top of it** and route the Intent to that existing instance. When used in conjunction with FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK, this flag locates any existing instances of the Activity in any task and brings it to the foreground.

You can achieve with by replacing `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK` with `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP`.

**Modified code:**

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(intent);
```

So, all the activities in back stack `onDestroy` method will be called including your `LoginActivity's onDestroy` method in the same order they inserted.

Answer (score 0):

```
 finishAffinity();
 startActivity(new Intent(this,ActivityA.class));
```

For navigating from last(ActivityD) to first activity(ActivityA) after clearing backstack, try above code.

1. Clear all activities from backstack using.
2. After that call the activity.